# I have tried download file using Laravel Storage but i got error from browser

Tags: php, laravel

I have to download file via browser so i use laravel storage but i got some error. Firefox return me this error. How can i fix that?

This is my request method

```
return Storage::disk('sftp')->download('some_file.png');
```

by the way i'm sure this file exists in the server and this is my error via firefox browser

> /tmp/mozilla_umut0/TcGfuMpx.png.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read. Try again later, or contact the server administrator.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is not about laravel or php. The error is coming from the browser as you mentioned. Try to use another browser to see if the error still occurs.

With a quick look i found [this](https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-fix-source-file-could-not-be-read-error-on-firefox/).

Comment: Thanks but i tried all of it. It doesn't works. I use another browser i got same error again. Do you think it could be related to permissions? Also i can download file in my local but it doesn't download on production side.